# How to remove rendered circle in highcharts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I had rendered group of circles .but After zoom in I need to remove them .How can I do that?

here is code for render circles

```
var allPoints = localStorage.getItem('points');
//console.log(allPoints);
if(allPoints !== null) {
    var allPointsDetail = JSON.parse(allPoints);
    _.each(allPointsDetail, function(pointDetail, key) {
        var pointCordinate =[];
        pointCordinate[0] = pointDetail['x'];
        pointCordinate[1] = pointDetail['y'];
        RP.drawReportingPoints(pointCordinate,pointDetail);
    });
}
```

similarly afterzoom in  I had done this much

```
xAxis: {
    events: {
        afterSetExtremes: function(event){
            if (this.getExtremes().dataMin < event.min){
                var top_position =  RP.chart.yAxis[0].toPixels(RP.$valueInput.val());
                RP.$handleContainer.css('top', top_position);
                var allPoints = localStorage.getItem('points');

                // allPoints give points detail which is stored in localStorage.these point should remove from chart which was drawn before

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: At the beginning, could you reproduce your example as live demo?

Comment: Are you drawing these circles using this: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer.circle?

Comment: Yes Mark. I am using  renderer.circle. And problem was already solved.

Comment: How did you solve the problem? @Nabina